# My webpage is not looking as good as when i coding (Different screen sizes)

Tags: css

I was creating an Etc-a-Sketch game for the Odin Project curriculum.
Everything seemed ok for me, but unfortunately when i uploaded everything on Github and saw it on a bigger screen, things didn't look the same.

What i was seeing in my VM in which i was coding:
[image]

and what i am seeing in my PC screen (not via VM:)[image]

I will also share my code in case you want to have a look.

```js
let color = "black";
let click = true;

//Populates the Grid
function populateBoard(size){
 let board = document.querySelector(".board");
 board.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`
 board.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`

 let amount = size*size
 for (i=0; i < amount; i++){
     let square = document.createElement('div');
     square.classList.add('div-squares')
     square.addEventListener('mouseover', colorSquare)
     square.style.backgroundColor = "white";
     board.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', square);
  }
}

populateBoard(16);

//New grid 
let newGridButton = document.querySelector("#new-grid");
newGridButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    changeSize(newSize.value);
})

function changeSize(input){
        let squares = document.querySelectorAll("div .div-squares");
        squares.forEach((div) => div.remove());
        populateBoard(input);
}

//Function for RGB colors
function colorSquare() {
    if (click) {
      if(color === 'random') {
          this.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${Math.random()*360}, 100%, 50%)`
      } else {    
      this.style.backgroundColor = color;
      }
 }
}

//Range bar & display
let newSize = document.querySelector("#new-size");
newSize.value = 16;
let displaySize = document.querySelector("#size-label");
displaySize.textContent = newSize.value;
newSize.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    displaySize.textContent = newSize.value
})



function changeColor(choice) {
    color = choice;
}

//Clears the board
function resetBoard(){
    let squares = document.querySelectorAll("div .div-squares");
        squares.forEach((div) => div.style.backgroundColor = "white");
}

//Coloring Mode
document.querySelector('.board').addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if(e.target.className != "board"){
    click = !click
    if(click){
        document.querySelector(".mode-not-coloring").textContent = "";
        document.querySelector(".mode-coloring").textContent = "Coloring"
    } else {
        document.querySelector(".mode-not-coloring").textContent = "Not Coloring";
        document.querySelector(".mode-coloring").textContent = ""  
    }
  }
});

//Function:Random Color for Coloring mode
let colorText = document.querySelector(".mode-coloring");

function getRandomColor(){
    let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    let colour = '#';
    for (let i=0; i <6; i++) {
        colour += letters[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)];
    }
    return colour;
}

function flashRandomColor(){
    colorText.style.color = getRandomColor();
}

setInterval(flashRandomColor,700);
```

```css
/* Main Board */
.board{
    display:grid;
    width: 65vh;
    height: 65vh;
    border: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.404) solid;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    margin-right: 6vh;
    box-sizing: content-box;

}

.div-squares{
    border: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.041) solid;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.div-squares:hover{
    background-color: #1381ad !important;
}

/* Header */
.title{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #31748f;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 25px;
}

h1{
    color: #f25602;
    font-family: "Alfa Slab One";
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #f3cfbc;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.content{
    padding: 40px 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 200px;
}

.coloring-text{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
/* New Grid Button */
#new-grid{
    display: block;
    background-color: #f25602;
}

#new-grid:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.199);
    background-color: #500d04;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    color: #d9f3ed;
}

#new-grid:active {
    border: 1px solid #300a0a;
    transition: all 0s ease;
    background-color: #7bcfb3;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.199);
}

#new-size{
    width: 16vw;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.left-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.mode, .mode-coloring, .mode-not-coloring{
    font-family: "Iceland";
    font-size: 40px;
}

button{
    background-color: #3ba1c9;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: "Iceland";
    border-radius: 24px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 18vw;
    height: 3vh;
}

button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.199);
    background-color: #042b50;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    color: #d9f3ed;
}

button:active {
    border: 1px solid #300a0a;
    transition: all 0s ease;
    background-color: #7bcfb3;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.199);
}

.buttons{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 15px;
}

#clear-button{
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: white;
}

#clear-button:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.199);
    background-color: #042b50;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    color: #d9f3ed;
}

#clear-button:active{
    border: 1px solid #300a0a;
    transition: all 0s ease;
    background-color: #7bcfb3;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.199);
}

.range-bar{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
}

.range-bar-button{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* align-items: center; */
}

#size-label{
    font-family: "Iceland";
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* Footer */
footer{
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    background: #1381ad;
    color: #f85903;
    font-family: "Iceland";
    font-size: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    margin-top: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.git-pic{
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
}

.git-pic:hover{
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa Slab One">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Iceland">
    <title>Etc-A-Sketch</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Etc-A-Sketch</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="content">

            <div class="left-content">

                <div class="coloring-text">
                  <div class="mode">Mode:&nbsp;</div>
                  <div class="mode-coloring">Coloring</div>
                  <div class="mode-not-coloring"></div>
                </div>

              <div class="buttons">
                  <button onclick="changeColor('black')">Black</button>
                  <button onclick="changeColor('white')">Erasor</button>
                  <button onclick="changeColor('grey')">Gray</button> 
                  <button onclick="changeColor('random')">Random</button>
                  <button id="clear-button" onclick="resetBoard()">Clear</button>
              </div>

              <div class="range-bar-button">
                <div class="range-bar">
                  <input id="new-size" type="range" min="2" max="100" value="16"/>
                  <label id="size-label"></label>
                </div>
    
                  <button id="new-grid">New grid size</button>
              </div>
            </div>
             
              <div class="board"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <p>
            Copyright ©
            <script>
                document.write(new Date().getFullYear())
            </script>
            georgan1987
            <a href="https://github.com/georgan1987"><img src="./GitHub-Mark-32px.png" alt="GitHub Logo" class="git-pic">    </a>
        </p>
    
    </footer>
    
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

When i run the snippet the result is also messed up in the small window.

Could please someone share with me some advices?

I searched for similar questions and probably me not using Media Query is the issue, but we haven't learned it yet in the curriculum. I checked that it's a bit further in the curriculum.

Any advice on how i could fix this without Media Query (for now), would be very helpful!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You could use JavaScript (change styles depending on the screen size) to simulate the CSS' media query behaviour. But I would still recommend to use media queries – it's easier.

Comment: U require media query for the size adjustment